# Smack Multi user chat set answer XMPPError: bad-request-cancel

Tags: xmpp, smack

I developed android chat app by using XMPP server (prosody) and smack library. When I trying to create chat room, the room is created successfully, but when I send configuration Form this error is appears:

XMPPError: bad-request - cancel

My Code:

```
EntityBareJid entityBareJid = null;

entityBareJid = JidCreate.entityBareFrom("room5@conference.MyServiceName.com");

MultiUserChat muc = multiUserChatManager.getMultiUserChat(entityBareJid);

muc.join(Resourcepart.from("rshRoom5"));

Log.d("GROUP" , "Room now is created ...... ");

Form form = muc.getConfigurationForm();
Form answerForm = form.createAnswerForm();
answerForm.setAnswer("muc#roomconfig_persistentroom", true);
muc.sendConfigurationForm(answerForm);
```

And this is the muc component in server configuration file:

> Component "conference.MyServiceName.com" "muc"
>
> name = "chatrooms server"
>
> restrict_room_creation = false;

Comment: @saghul please can you answer my question.. thanks in advance

Comment: Could you post your error IQ body?